# Question about fixpoints and zero's on the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, logarithms, fixed-point-theorems, roots

Define property $A$ for an entire function $f(z)$ as

$1)$ $f(z)=0$ has exactly one solution being $z=0$

$2)$ $f(z)=z$ has exactly one solution $=>z=0$  (follows from $1)$ )

$3)$ $f(z)$ is not a polynomial.

Define property $B$ for an entire function $f(z)$ as

$1)$ $f(z)=f_1(z)$ with property $A$.

$2)$ $f_i(z)= ln(f_{i-1}(z)/z)$ for every positive integer $i$.

$3)$ $f_i(z)$ is entire and has property $A$ for every positive integer $i$.

I think there are no entire functions $f(z)$ that have property $B$.

Is that true ?

Comment: We clearly want $f_i'(0) = 1 \quad \forall\ i$, proof (or generation of example) may work by Taylor'ing at $z=0$ for big $i$...

Comment: @AlexR thats right.

Comment: A simpler question would be analytic near ( FIXED (for all i ) positive radius ) zero , and dropping the restriction of property A of only one solution to $f(z) = 0$.

Comment: Maybe I should change it to the modified question given in the above comment.

Comment: If you want to change the question so much, ask a new one. Would be interesting. I don't know the answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not even an entire function with property $A$.

Suppose $f$ had property $A$. Then $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$ is an entire function without zeros, not a polynomial, and $g(z) \neq 1$ for $z \neq 0$.

$\infty$ is an essential singularity of $g$ - since $g$ is not a polynomial, hence by the big theorem of Picard, $g$ assumes every complex value with **one** possible exception infinitely often in every set $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert > K\}$. But property $A$ demands that the two values $0$ and $1$ are omitted.

Comment: How is 1 omitted ? g(0) = 1 ?

Comment: It is omitted in $\{z : \lvert z\rvert > K\}$. And that can't happen by Picard's theorem if also $0$ is omitted there.

Comment: Yes I see now !

Comment: @DanielFischer Cool stuff there ;-) +1. It would still be interesting, if we weaken $(A)$, if we can get analogous $(B)$...

Comment: @AlexR Indeed. If we don't demand entire functions, it could be possible. I'm thinking about it, but have not found an answer yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll leave you alone with it, late-night over here ;-)

Comment: @AlexR A little past 1 AM here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Same here, but have work to do tomorrow

Comment: @AlexR Then have a good sleep.