# Questions about $\ln(z)$ recurrence and fixed points.

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, logarithms, fixed-point-theorems

Define property $A_R$ for an analytic function $f(z)$ as

$1)$ $f(z)=0$ has exactly one solution being $z=0$ for $|z|<R$ where $R$ is a radius. And $f(z)$ is analytic within the radius $R$ (centered at $0$).

$2)$ $f(z)=z$ has exactly one solution in the complex plane $=>z=0$  (follows from $1)$ )

$3)$ $f(z)$ is not a polynomial.

Define property $B_R$ for an analytic function $f(z)$ as

$1)$ $f(z)=f_1(z)$ with property $A_R$.

$2)$ $f_i(z)= \ln(f_{i-1}(z)/z)$ for every positive integer $i$.

$3)$ $f_i(z)$ is entire and has property $A_R$ for every positive integer $i$.

I think there are functions $f(z)$ that have property $B_R$ for some $R>1$.

Is that true ?

Is there a solution for any $R$ ?

Is there a way to describe $f_i$ easily ? How does $f_i$ behave or grow with respect to $i$ and/or large $z$ ?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489966/question-about-fixpoints-and-zeros-on-the-complex-plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer but to much for a comment.

If $|f(z)| < |e^{e^{...^z}}|$ , in other words if $|f(z)|$ grows slower than a repeated exponential function then :

For sufficiently large $i$ and large $z$ the equation for the fixpoints starts to get like $ln(ln(...ln(z)...)= z$ hence we can conclude that the norm of the fixpoints is bounded then.

Tommy1729 suggested trying $f(z) =$ $z/a$ or $a* sinh(z)$ for $a>\frac{3}{2}$.
( without thinking about it )